# Character of an Induced Representation

Tags: representation-theory, characters

In Fulton's book, page 34, it is stated that,

> To compute the character of $V = Ind\space W$, note that $g \in G$ maps $\sigma W $ to $g \sigma W$, so the trace is calculated from those cosets $\sigma$ with $g \sigma = \sigma$, i.e., $s^{-1}gs \in H $ for $s \in \sigma$.

Can you clarify this for me? I don't see the connection to the representation matrix and traces.

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to the following: let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space which is a direct sum of spaces $W_1, ... , W_m$.  Let $T$ be a linear isomorphism on $V$ which stabilizes $W_1, ... , W_t$, but permutes $W_{t+1}, ... , W_m$ among each other, stabilizing none of them.  If $V' = W_{t+1} \oplus \cdots \oplus W_m$, then $T$ stabilizes $V'$, and so

$$\operatorname{Tr} T = \sum\limits_{i=1}^t \operatorname{Tr} T|_{W_i} + \operatorname{Tr} T|_{V'}$$

But $\operatorname{Tr} T|_{V'} = 0$; choosing a basis for $V'$ out of bases for the $W_i : t + 1 \leq i \leq m$, it's easy to see that the matrix for $T|_{V'}$ has zeroes on the diagonal.

For example, if $T(W_1) =W_2, T(W_2) = W_3, T(W_3) = W_1$ then the matrix for $T$ will look like

$$\begin{pmatrix} & & \ast \\ \ast & & \\ & \ast & \end{pmatrix}$$

where $\ast$ are block matrices.